# Active code in XAML properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010

I have a situation where I want  UIElement to have a top margin of

```
((this.height / 2) - 70)
```

Currently, the XAML property is

```
Margin="0, 40, 0, 0"
```

How can I combine the equation above into my XAML? I know this is probably simple, but I can't figure out what terms to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at ExpressionConverter from Josh Twist -

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/The_Binding_you_wanted_from_day_one_in_WPF.aspx

Comment: Happy to help :). It will be great if you can post your code. Will be helpful for others.